# Child component adding/removing when used ngIf in same onclick function call

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a newbie in angular. Please guide me in this scenario. Thanks.
I have a parent component:
parent.component.html

```
<app-child1 (chartClick)="showChild($event)"></app-child1>
<app-child2 (levelOneChartClick)="showLevelTwoChild($event)" *ngIf="!showFirst"></app-child2>
```

parent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  showFirst: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() { }
  showChild = function (event) {
    this.showFirst = false;
   }
  showLevelTwoChild = function (event) {
    console.log("called once......");
    this.showFirst = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("called second");
      this.showFirst = false;
      }, 5000);
  }
```

child1.component.html

```
<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10">
            <canvas id="pieElement" (click)="onChartClick($event)"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

child1.component.ts

```
export class Child1Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  globals: Globals;
  @Output()
  chartClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  dataSets = [];
  pieChartOptions;

  constructor(private globals: Globals,private chidl1Service: Child1Service) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;
    let tempData = [];
    this.child1Service.getChild1Details().subscribe(data =>{
      //Subsccribing code goes here....
     // In here, get data from http service, and create a cumulative chart.
     }
    onChartClick(event: any) {
    this.chartClick.emit(event); //emmiting the event.
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
}
```

child1.component.html

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row justify-content-center" >
        <div *ngFor="let chart of array; let i = index">
            <canvas id="canvas{{i}}" #levelOneCanvas width="550" heigth="650" 
           (click)="onLevelOneChartClick($event,i)"></canvas> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

chidl2.component.ts

```
export class Child2Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Output() levelOneChartClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChildren('levelOneCanvas') levelOneCanvas: QueryList<any>;
  array = [];
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private globals: Globals) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
 onLevelOneChartClick(event, index) {
    this.levelOneChartClick.emit(event);
 }
```

Parent.component.html file has 2 child components. First child component will make a http call and display a chart. On click on that chart, shows its childs charts using child component two.
Once clicked on chart 2, chart 2 will become chart1 and chart 3 content has to be created in child2. 
My understanding is: which clicked on chart 2, I could update chart2 data with chart1 and remove chart2 data from dom. Do I dont have to destroy charts and stuff. after certain amount of time, chart3 data is to be populated in child2 component, which event emitter has that settimeout functionality. 
In child2.component.ts file, emitting an event using levelOneChartClick. I want to remove child2 from dom and after certain amount of time, re-add it again. Is this possible? in showLevelTwoChild method of parent.component.ts file, included a setTimeout method. But it is not working. Let me know if the question is not clear or you need more information, I can provide. 
Intentionally, did not add few content which is not required.

Another question on 'levelOneCanvas' template reference variable, First time only 4 charts will be displayed on child2 component. After removing them from dom using ngIf, still when I access levelOneCanvas template reference variable, shows the same content. Is there a way to reset that?

Comment: Could any one help on this?

Comment: can you make a stackblitz